# Folder created, owned by root (android create project)

Tags: permissions, scripts, android

I'm running a script provided in the Android SDK, to create a project folder. But the folder is created with root ownership, and I need to work within it.

I had the audacity not to install the SDK under my home folder, but rather under usr/local/lib... and I am wondering, since this is a priveleged location which I usually have to use `sudo su` to access, could this be the reason the project folder is owned by root? Or do the permissions assigned on folder creation fall entirely to the script that creates the project folder?

Any other tips would be appreciated since I don't want to spend my days having to `sudo` incessantly... I need to set up some complex build scripts and would prefer it if that can be achieved by the user i.e. me, not root. P.S. I'm not sure if it's appropriate to go fiddle with these permissions if this is what has been set by whatever application / script, or I'd just do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally anything in /usr/local is either owned by root or by the group "staff" in Debian distros. You can create a group that can write to that directory and add yourself to it if you want.

```
sudo groupadd usrlocal
sudo usermod -a -G usrlocal $user
sudo chown -R /usr/local/* root:usrlocal
sudo chmod 750 /usr/local
```

Also you can use the setuid bit to ensure that the SDK is always launched by root.

```
sudo chmod +t /usr/local/sdk/script
```

I think that may be what's causing your problem, if I understand correctly. If you need write access use '770' instead.

**Edit:** (For the sake of completeness) Unless configured otherwise, any files a program it creates will be owned by the user that's running the program. If the script/program does not need root privileges, change the ownership to yourself:

```
sudo chown /path/to/exec $user:$user
```

Comment: Thanks Chev, this looks helpful. However, can you answer the part about whether or not the script _in_ usr/local is likely to be the culprit for causing the project folder (which is created under home) to be owned by root? Or is creating folders with root ownership a kind of system default in Debian? This is something I'd like to know for future reference.

Comment: That is likely because it is running as root, so the files that it saves are also owned by root. I'd suggest maybe changing the permisions to 755 or perhaps saving them in a different directory, like /root/development or something. Does it need to be ran as root? It's better if it does not have to be...

Comment: In that case, I could probably extract the SDK and NDK folders into home and keep ownership for myself, preventing any of this tomfoolery. If not, I have your fallback method with user groups. Thank you, this should give me everything I need. :)

Comment: If it doesn't need to run as root, than just do:

`chown $user:$user /path/to/executable`

And than it will run as you.